# inner join using same table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two sql queries (from 1 table) that I need to join but I'm always getting an error when I tried to join them.

1st table: This is the complete table.

```
Select Server, Network, ReservationIP, ReservationMAC, ReservationName
from ScopeReservations
```

**Result** (truncated. this is a very table)

```
> Server    Network ReservationIP   ReservationMAC  ReservationName
> Server1   10.3.64.32  10.3.64.36  000d5d08e83c    pr-bnea06-a01-a
> Server2   10.3.64.32  10.3.64.37  000d5d08278c    pr-bnea06-a02-a
```

2nd table: All those with duplicate value in ReservationMAC

```
 Select ReservationMAC, COUNT(*) from DHCP_ScopeReservations
    group by ReservationMAC
    having count(*) > 1
    order by ReservationMAC
```

**Result:**

```
ReservationMAC  (No column name)
0000850a3477    2
0000854b8328    2
85731867    2
```

The result that I need is this.

```
Server  Network         ReservationIP   ReservationMAC  ReservationName
Server1 10.233.192.0    10.233.192.5    0000850a3477    pq2217a.
Server2 10.233.196.0    10.233.197.129  0000850a3477    pq2217.
Server1 10.80.16.0      10.80.17.13     0000854b8328    PQ090.
Server2 10.80.70.32     10.80.70.47     0000854b8328    Canon4B8328.
```

**Also,** Result should not contain those with the same reservationIP and reservationMAC.
Not included in result:

```
Server  Network     ReservationIP  ReservationMAC   ReservationName
Server1 10.34.57.0  10.34.57.10    011               vh101r
Server2 10.34.57.1  10.34.57.10    011               vh102r
Server1 10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22    0000681569af      ac-gpo069
Server2 10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22    0000681569af      ac-gpo069
```

The result should all those with duplicate entry in ReservationMac column. The result must contain all columns of the table.

---

What I tried to do:

```
Select a.Server, a.Network, a.ReservationIP, a.ReservationMAC,
a.ReservationName 
from DHCP_ScopeReservations a
INNER JOIN 
    (
        Select ReservationMAC, COUNT(*)
        from DHCP_ScopeReservations
        group by ReservationMAC
        having count(*) > 1
    ) dt ON a.ReservationMAC=dt.ReservationMAC
```

Error was

> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   No column name was specified for column 2 of 'dt'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an alias for `COUNT(*)`:

```
Select a.Server, a.Network, a.ReservationIP, 
       a.ReservationMAC, a.ReservationName, dt.cnt 
from DHCP_ScopeReservations a   
INNER JOIN (Select ReservationMAC, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            from DHCP_ScopeReservations             
            group by ReservationMAC               
            having count(*) > 1) dt 
ON a.ReservationMAC=dt.ReservationMAC
```

Using the `cnt` alias you can now access the number of duplicates in the `SELECT` clause of the outer query.

Comment: thank you! but how about not including those duplicate with identical columns in the results?

Comment: @lulala You want to include in the result set, in case of a duplicate `ReservationMAC`, only one matching record from table `DHCP_ScopeReservations`?

Comment: all good now.  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664962/join-two-queried-tables/29665286?noredirect=1#comment47472177_29665286

Answer (score 1):

Using a `JOIN` you can get the desired result, like this:

```
SELECT Server, Network, ReservationIP, s.ReservationMAC, ReservationName
FROM ScopeReservations s
JOIN (
  SELECT ReservationMAC 
  FROM DHCP_ScopeReservations
  GROUP BY ReservationMAC
  HAVING COUNT(ReservationMAC) > 1
) dupe
ON s.ReservationMAC = dupe.ReservationMAC
```

Comment: One more thing. I need to add a where clause to remove those with same reservationIP from the final result. Is this possible. Remove this output: (header)"Server Network ReservationIP ReservationMAC ReservationName"
(1st result) Server1 10.16.175.0 10.16.175.203 000081 ups-mume-042a                                  
(2nd result) Server2 10.64.160.0 10.64.177.61 000081 pq2331

Comment: @lulala sorry i dont understand. what is meant by `same reservationIP`?

Comment: all good now. I posted a different question.   - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664962/join-two-queried-tables/29665286?noredirect=1#comment47472177_29665286