# Join two queried tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

How do I join these two tables? Im guessing it will either a left or right join but I can't determine the syntax.

Two queries from the same table generated two tables:

Table 1. Get all those with the same entry in ReservationMAC and ReservationIP column:

> ```
> Select a.Server, a.Network, a.ReservationIP, a.ReservationMAC, a.ReservationName, dt.cnt 
>   from Dashboard.dbo.DHCP_ScopeReservations a
>       INNER JOIN (Select ReservationIP, ReservationMAC, COUNT(ReservationMAC) AS cnt from Dashboard.dbo.DHCP_ScopeReservations
>                   group by ReservationIP, ReservationMAC
>                   having count(ReservationMAC) > 1  
>
>                   ) dt ON a.ReservationMAC=dt.ReservationMAC AND a.ReservationIP=dt.ReservationIP
>   order by ReservationMAC
> ```
>
> Result:

```
Server  network ReservationIP   ReservationMAC  ReservationNAme cnt
S1  10.34.57.0  10.34.57.10     0               vhpa101         2
S2  10.34.57.0  10.34.57.10     0               vhvpa101        2
S3  10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22    0000681569af     ac-gpo069       2
S4  10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22    0000681569af     ac-gpo069       2
S5  10.232.8.0  10.232.11.51    6.82E+06        ac-gpob14       2
S6  10.232.8.0  10.232.11.51    6.82E+06        ac-gpob14       2
```

Table2. Get all those with the same entry only in ReservationMAC column

> ```
> Select a.Server, a.Network, a.ReservationIP, a.ReservationMAC, a.ReservationName, dt.cnt 
> from Dashboard.dbo.DHCP_ScopeReservations a
>   INNER JOIN (Select ReservationMAC, COUNT(ReservationMAC) AS cnt from Dashboard.dbo.DHCP_ScopeReservations
>               group by ReservationMAC
>               having count(ReservationMAC) > 1
>
>               ) dt ON a.ReservationMAC=dt.ReservationMAC 
>               order by ReservationMAC
> ```

```
Result: 
Server  network ReservationIP   ReservationMAC  ReservationNAme cnt
S1  10.16.175.0 10.16.175.203   0               ups-mume-042a       2
S2  10.64.160.0 10.64.177.61    0               pq2331              2
S3  10.34.57.0  10.34.57.10     0               vhpa101             2
S4  10.34.57.0  10.34.57.10     0               vhvpa101            2
S1  10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22     0000681569af    ac-gpo069           2
S2  10.206.0.0  10.206.3.22     0000681569af    ac-gpo069           2
S3  10.232.8.0  10.232.11.51    6.82E+06        ac-gpob14       2
S4  10.232.8.0  10.232.11.51    6.82E+06        ac-gpob14       2
```

I need to rejoin these two and the end result should be a table whose 
ReservationMAC column match but the ReservationIP column doesnot match. I don't care about the other columns but I need it in the result. 
Result:

```
Server  network ReservationIP   ReservationMAC  ReservationNAme cnt
S1  10.16.175.0 10.16.175.203   0               ups-mume-042a   2
S2  10.64.160.0 10.64.177.61    0               pq2331          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your queries in parenthesis, and give them an alias to join on.

```
  select q1.server, q1.network, q1.reservationip, q1.reservationmac, q1.reservationname, q1.cnt
    from
      (your first query) q1
      INNER JOIN
      (your second query) q2
      ON q1.reservationmac = q2.reservationmac and q1.reservationip <> q2.reservationip
```

As an alternative, you could create views out of your two queries in order to make the query a little bit more manageable.

Comment: hmm doesn't seem correct. Inner join will result values similar in both tables, right?

Comment: no. it just wont include rows that don't match the criteria. in this case, it is joining on equivalent `reservationmac`, and DIFFERENT `reservationip`. you aren't forced to join on equality, you can just as effectively join on inequality or any other boolean comparison

Comment: @lulala http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce2c/1 for a demo of the query running. which gives four results as you'd expect, as there are two rows in the first query with the same mac and differing ips to two rows in the second query.